# Erro no vetor(matriz unidimensional)

Tags: c++

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado neste algoritmo?

Faça um programa onde o usuário entre com N valores e armazene os 10 primeiros números pares em um vetor chamado par. Quando chegar ao décimo número par, encerre o programa e imprima o vetor....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int par[10],a,count;

main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    while(count<10){
            printf("Digite um número: \n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            if(a%2==0){
                par[a]=a;
                a++;
                count++;
            }//fim do if

    }//fim do while
    for(a=1;a<=10;a++){
        printf("valores de vetor: %d \n",par[a]);
    }//fim do for



    system("pause");
}//fim do main
```

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte, na hora de imprimir os números pares do primeiro vetor até o nono, vai tudo ok, porém a impressão do décimo vetor, está somando "1" ao número, por exemplo se eu digitar as seguintes sequências, 
2 4 6 8 10 2 4 6 8 10 
ele irá imprimir:
 2 4 6 8 10 2 4 6 8 "11"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os arrays em C++ são iniciados em 0. Acredito que o erro esteja no loop final, onde você está iterando o array fora do intervalo desejado.

Altere seu loop final para

```
for(a=0;a<10;a++){
    printf("valores de vetor: %d \n",par[a]);
}//fim do for
```

Além disso, utilize a variável `count` ao invés do `a` para preencher o array. ( e retire o `a++` desnecessário )

```
while(count<10){
   printf("Digite um número: \n");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   if(a%2==0){
     par[count]=a;
      count++;
   }//fim do if
}
```

Segue algoritmo funcionando conforme desejado: http://ideone.com/7LOOBg

Comment: Felipe ainda assim o resultado final deu problema, na hora da impressão dos resultado na tela, ele está imprimindo o décimo número 11 ao invés de 10, se puder copie o código e faça um teste você mesmo...

Comment: @AdrianRoger Aqui está executando normal. Utilizei a seguinte interface para testar: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: E se notar, não há necessidade de modificar meu loop de impressão, pois 'a' começa em '1' e termina em menos ou igual a '10'.

Comment: Aqui sempre imprime valor errado para a décima parte do vetor, é como se somasse 1 ao número digitado.

Comment: @AdrianRoger Há a necessidade de alterar o loop final, caso contrário você irá ignorar a primeira posição do vetor ( que é 0, e não 1 ) e acessará uma não existente ( a última posição é 9, e não 10 )

Comment: Ainda assim está imprimindo 11 para o ultimo valor do vetor, a princípio a condição é que seja par para que aceite, ele conta, mas na hora de imprimir ele soma 1 ao último número, pq isso?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não consigo reproduzir o erro. O algoritmo original possui problemas, corrigidos no algoritmo que sugeri. Tem certeza que está compilando o código que passei? No site informado ele funciona